# `npm install weak` on Windows 8.1: error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'weakref.vcxproj' is invalid

Tags: windows, node.js, visual-studio-2010

Does anybody know why I'm getting:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'weakref.vcxproj' is invalid. Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Users\mark\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\weak\build\weakref.vcxproj]
```

when attempting to `npm install weak` on Windows 8.1?

I tried installing [Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express), adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcpackages` as an environment variable and running `npm install weak` from the `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)` to no avail.

I've also installed the [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) but it doesn't seem to ship with a command prompt so I'm not really sure what to do there.